# What is difference between Decode vs NVL function?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been wanting to know for some time, how the internal working is done for DECODE and NVL function. 
Does the DECODE function have more overhead in case the number of arguments in it are more?

Also, does the NVL function evaluate the value given instead of NULL, even if the original value is not NULL
e.g. for NVL(COL1, func_call()) 
would the func_call() be calculated even if COL1 is not NULL. In that case, it might create performance issue if the COL1 is rarely null and func_call() is time consuming.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NVL always evaluates both arguments, so even if COL1 is not null it will evaluate func_call()

Decode does short circuit, so the first valid condition stops execution.

With similar arguments performance is pretty similar between the two.  I usually just choose based on simplicity - NVL unless I need to have a if-then-else type construct.

----EDIT----

In situations where you do use NVL if you find yourself doing nested NVL like nvl(col1, nvl(col2, '0')) take a look at the coalesce function where this would be expressed as coalesce(col1, col2, '0') - returns the first non-null argument

Comment: Thank @Kelly. Why I asked this question is because I tend to face situations where I have to use multiple NVL or DECODE in my query. In this situation which function will be better suited in terms of performance?

Comment: In this case I might use decode since it does short circuit.  If func_call is time consuming it would be better to only call it when necessary, and NVL is not inherently faster to make up for not short circuiting.

Comment: One other thing: in situations where you do use NVL if you find yourself doing nested NVL like nvl(col1, nvl(col2, '0')) take a look at the coalesce function where this would be expressed as coalesce(col1, col2, '0') - returns the first non-null argument.

Comment: +1 for Kelly's comment there -- Coalesce() is more flexible, is ANSI standard, and features short-circuit evaluation. Can you update your answer?